# Android - drawing cache - when is it useful?

Tags: android, caching

I am reading about `setDrawingCacheEnabled` and `getDrawingCache` and I was wondering when is it good to use it or when its not good.

Basically in my case I have an `HorizontalScrollView` with many things inside it so its scrolls left/right and most of the things are not visible.

If I use `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` on the views, does it help?  or this is only when I use custom views and I call `getDrawingCache()`?

Is there any other 'cache' way to use in a `HorizontalScrollView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TouchInterceptor.java](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/TouchInterceptor.java) - This is class responsible for reordering your playlist in the default music player. It uses `setDrawingCacheEnabled` when you start dragging the current view. Basically, it creates a bitmap from the `ListView` item and drag it. Take a closer look at `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.

Comment: The link is dead. Unfortunately I couldn't find any good example of using it with onInterceptTouchEvent method.

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/TouchInterceptor.java

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely useful for screenshots as Marcel said. It is also very useful performance-wise, as that is what it was created for. It does use up more memory, as you render the view into a bitmap first.

What you do is, you `setDrawingCacheEnabled` to `true`, call `getDrawingCache` which returns a bitmap and store this bitmap. In `onDraw`, you do draw the bitmap you got if the cache is on, or the view otherwise. This can be very nice when scrolling.

Comment: I am trying to drag and drop images from one cell of a grid to another. Can I use this mechanism ? If yes then what should I change on my code ? Please help me?